# Error converting Sum[Field] as numeric or float

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-convert

I am using a function to get total of a column field  is :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTwoWeeklyWorkTime](@EmployeeID as int,@PayPeriodID as varchar(10))

  RETURNS int

  AS
  BEGIN
  DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
  DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

   Select @StartDate=[PeriodStartDate],@EndDate=[PeriodEndDate] from PayPeriod where PayPeriodId=@PayPeriodID
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @ResultVar numeric(10,2)

SELECT @ResultVar=

  Sum([WorkingTime])/60

  FROM [DayLog] Where EmployeeId =@EmployeeID AND CreatedDate between @StartDate AND @endDate 

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN Isnull(@ResultVar,0)
```

END

At the line

```
                 Sum([WorkingTime])/60
```

I get the result as int.
How to convert or Cast it into numeric or float..?

**EDIT**

I tried flowing:

```
             Sum(Cast([WorkingTime] as float))/60

             Sum([WorkingTime])/60.0
```

But no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can *calculate* it as a `float` using

```
Sum(Cast([WorkingTime] as float))/60
```

but you also need to change your function return value to `float`:

```
RETURNS float
```

Answer (score 0):

`INT / INT` would result in an `INT`, even though result could be a fraction.

Use this:

```
Sum([WorkingTime]) / 60.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
RETURNS int
```

to

> RETURNS decimal (10,2)